# How to execute upload parallel in from same session ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload multiple files in ASP.NET MVC. But uploading files sequence is sequence suppose if I call upload function with two times then it will wait complete first one then second one complete.

All request are hanged on IIS worker process. I have user `SesssionStateBehave readonly` then upload time reduce but pattern is same. Please help me upload files fast.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> updateDataList()
{
    var client = GetHttpClientWithBearerToken();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

    var url = baseUrl+ "/api/InsertTriggersData";

    try
    {
        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpContext.Request.Form["Action"]), "Action");
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpContext.Request.Form["Remarks"]), "Remarks");

        int FilesCount = HttpContext.Request.Files.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < FilesCount; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = HttpContext.Request.Files[i];
            requestContent.Add(new StreamContent(file.InputStream), "file" + i, file.FileName);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);

        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var returnData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var jsonResult = Json(new { success = true, Content = returnData }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return jsonResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, Content = "-1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logging.WriteLog(e.Message, Logging.LogMsgType.General);
    }

    return Json(new { success = false, Content = "-1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```